# Why does this Flask function take an error argument?

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I'm learning python and I'm trying to build a website. I'm at the point where you need to handle errors but I don't understand the example that is given in the Flask documentation:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return render_template('error.html'), 404
```

Why do you need to type `not_found(error):` instead of `not_found():`?

Comment: Because that's not a view function. It's an [error handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@app.errorhandler()` doesn't register a regular view. It registers an [error handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers). Error handlers are passed the error object, so they can determine how best to produce an alternate view. From the documentation:

> An error handler is a function that returns a response when a type of error is raised, similar to how a view is a function that returns a response when a request URL is matched. **It is passed the instance of the error being handled**, which is most likely a `HTTPException`.

*(Bold emphasis mine)*

You can't find this error information on the `request` object, because errors like these are caused by the normal view handling the current request producing an error.

The normal path is:

- Request comes in
- Flask finds the right view to run and calls it
- The view encounters a problem and raises a 404 not found error, by calling `abort(404)`
- Flask finds a matching error handler and calls it *with the error object*.
- The error handler response is sent back to the browser.